# Relative paths of two moving particles wrt each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I asked this question  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4286718/  on math stack exchange but got almost no answer.

> Two particles $P_1$ and $P_2$  are moving on two smooth  $ f(x),g(x) $ curves starting from  $(x_1,y_1)$  , $(x_2,y_2)$ at $t=0$  and uniform speeds $v_1$ and $v_2$,in the positive direction of $x$-axis. Can we find the relative paths of $P_1$ and $P_2$ wrt to each other as a function of of $ v_1,v_2,t$?.

Here is what I have done so far:
When the x position of  the particle is $x$ at time $t$ ,we have:
$$ \int_0^x \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx=vt,$$    assuming the particle is at $(0,0)$ at $t=0.$
Now for as simple a function as $y=x^2$, the above equation becomes  $$ \int_0^x \sqrt{1+4x^2}dx=vt $$ which is very difficult to solve for $x$ in terms of $v$ and $t$.  If we differentiate the first equation wrt x, we get:
$$\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}=v\frac{dt}{dx}= \frac{v}{\frac{dx}{dt}} .$$ I have no idea how to proceed further and express  $x$ as a function of $t$.Any hints/sugggestions/links are  greatly appreciated.

**PS:-** The point is to precisely to compute $x$ as function of $t$ ,given the partice moves with UNIFORM SPEED v
on the curve  $y=f(x).$ We do know the component of instantaneous velocity at $x$ ,which can easily be shown
to be $vcos(tan^{−1}(x)) $,but again the question is what is  $x(t)$ ?

Comment: Could you clarify the directions of $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Comment: they speed  and not velocities

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what is the direction of their velocity vectors? E.g. are they perpendicular? Is one along the x-axis and the other along the y-axis? Without this info, we can't work it out

Comment: The particles are moving along the curves while maintaining a uniform speeds.  i suppose the direction  of their velocities at any time t  is along the tangent to the respective curves. For instance ,let us say starting from origin the particles start in  forward direction moving along the parabola $y=x^2$  and $y=\sinx $ while maintaining  constant speeds. I also made an edit . Does that make it clear now or not?

Comment: Oh okay, my bad I misinterpreted that.

Comment: the phrase "in the positive x direction" is confusing... are the direction of movement changing over time? can you picture the shape of their trajectory?

Comment: The first equation you used is enough to find out $x(t)$, but I think that it is not always possible to express $x(t)$ as a standard mathematical function of v and t which you want to find out. It depends on $f(x)$ if x(t) will be expressible in combination of standard mathematical function. For example for f(x) = x, on solving the equation we get $x(t) = \frac{vt}{\sqrt(2)}$, but for your example of y = x^2, on solving you will get $\frac{1}{4}*(2x*\sqrt(1+4x^2)+sinh^{-1}(2x)) = vt$ now you cannot solve this equation and find out x(t) as some nice function(even a defined function) of v and t.

Comment: $~\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}=v\frac{dt}{dx}~ $ or $~\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}~$ this is your differential equation that you have to solve